# Awesome CV editing

Tags: awesome-cv

Could someone please help me to edit the spacing of the line which contains details like phone number, email address, linkedin id etc. I entered only my mail id and contact number. But, that line is not in the centre of the page. It is shifted a bit towards left. Whereas if I enter mail id, contact number and linkedin id, the line will be in the centre of the page. Someone please help me resolve this problem. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You could see these links,for example: https://www.overleaf.com/14195527jfgprbrrnqtc#/54837237/, https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/tree/master/examples,

Answer (score 1):

I tested the sharelatex edition and found the problem you mentioned in your question.

Seems that the documentclass have been improved from then and it is here:

https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls

(Download and use this file instead)

The result is much better but it still leaves a space at the end of the email that makes the result to seem not perfectly centered. (See carefully below at second picture and compare with my fixed third)

By changing the lines 430-516 to:

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{\headertextwidth}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{L}}{\raggedright}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{\raggedleft}{\centering}}
        \headerfirstnamestyle{\@firstname}\headerlastnamestyle{{}\acvHeaderNameDelim\@lastname}%
        \\[\acvHeaderAfterNameSkip]%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@position}}{}{\headerpositionstyle{\@position\\[\acvHeaderAfterPositionSkip]}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@address}}{}{\headeraddressstyle{\@address\\[\acvHeaderAfterAddressSkip]}}%
        \headersocialstyle{%
          \newbool{isstart}%
          \setbool{isstart}{true}%
          \def\isntstart{$\;$\setbool{isstart}{false}}%koleygr:Used this command as a macro: 
%(for faster and not for better) The idea is that we need a space on start of
% "social" elements because on end it will always be one .
%The maintainer can use better way for the space of cource
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \isntstart%
              \faMobile\acvHeaderIconSep\@mobile%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{mailto:\@email}{\faEnvelope\acvHeaderIconSep\@email}%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{http://\@homepage}{\faHome\acvHeaderIconSep\@homepage}%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@github}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{https://github.com/\@github}{\faGithubSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@github}%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@gitlab}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{https://gitlab.com/\@gitlab}{\faGitlab\acvHeaderIconSep\@gitlab}%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@stackoverflowid}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/\@stackoverflowid}{\faStackOverflow\acvHeaderIconSep\@stackoverflowname}%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@linkedin}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\@linkedin}{\faLinkedinSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@linkedin}%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@twitter}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{https://twitter.com/\@twitter}{\faTwitter\acvHeaderIconSep\@twitter}%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \faSkype\acvHeaderIconSep\@skype%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@reddit}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{https://www.reddit.com/user/\@reddit}{\faReddit\acvHeaderIconSep\@reddit}%
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@xing}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \href{https://www.xing.com/profile/\@xing}{\faXingSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@xing}
            }%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}%
            {}%
            {%
              \ifbool{isstart}{\isntstart}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
              \@extrainfo%
            }%
        } \\[\acvHeaderAfterSocialSkip]%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
          {}%
          {\headerquotestyle{\@quote\\}\vspace{\acvHeaderAfterQuoteSkip}}%
\end{minipage}%
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: I suppose you can live with second edition too (second photo without the fix)